# ASP.NET MVC - XVal clientside validation of dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, xval, date-format

I'm having some problems with xVal's clientside validation when it comes to dates. I can't get it to work with a swedish date format which is yyyy-mm-dd, it only seems to work with mm/dd/yyyy. Is there a way to make it work with other date formats?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Date Validation in Chrome](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031142810/http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2009/10/29/jquery-date-validation-in-chrome.aspx)

Hope this entry.